# Variable Base with Variable as Factor in Exponent, Find Value

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

I saw a problem recently that looked like this:

Assume $w$ and $z$ are positive.  If $z^{4w} = 64$, what does $z^{6w}$ equal?

And I had absolutely no idea how to even begin attempting this equation.  How could I have gone about figuring out the answer?  This question was multiple choice, though I don't remember the answers available to me.

Comment: What's the relationship between $a,b,z,w$?

Comment: Sorry, "a" and "b" were mistakes on my part.  It should have been "z" and "w" only.

Comment: Well then, do you know that $x^{ab} = (x^a)^b$?

Comment: Yes, but I'm not sure how to apply that knowledge to this problem.

Comment: $4 \times \frac{3}{2} = 6$.

Comment: So then...Uhm...I'm still unsure as to how to answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given $z^{4w} = 64, z^{6w} =$ ?

We need to find a relationship between the exponents. Since $x^{ab} = (x^{a})^b$,

$$\Large{z^{6w} = z^{4w\cdot1.5}} = (z^{4w})^{1.5} = 64^{1.5} = 512$$

Comment: Oh!  Thank you!  Now it makes sense!!  :D